# Aspect Based Sentiment Assignment

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, sentiment-analysis

I was working on Aspect based sentiment analysis using Spacy dependent parser . In simple sentences such as " Car is good" it works properly , but when a slightly complex sentences arrives such as " Car is good in terms of mileage " it fails to assign positive sentiment for mileage and assigns it to car instead. Iam not able to relate mileage with good in following spacy parser. How to establish such a relation , If somebody could give a high level idea. 
[Good and mileage are not at all related here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl921.png)

Comment: I'm afraid you'd need to write more complex rules. For instance refer to this research paper: [A Rule-Based Approach to Aspect Extraction from Product Reviews](https://sentic.net/aspect-parser.pdf)